# How to implement Oauth Refresh Token in Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

Startup.Auth code:

```
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new FirebirdAuthorizationServerProvider(PublicClientId),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
```

I'm using FirebirdProvider, context and in props i add access token, this is the definition of my function:

```
  public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
......
                        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, identity);
                        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
                        context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

This is my call to get a token:

```
  public async Task<User> GetUserToken(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                User user = new User();
                if (username == null || password == null || !CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                    return null;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpContent requestContent = new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&login_type=" + "sys_dash_users", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("Token", requestContent);
                if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonMessage;
                    using (Stream responseStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                    {
                        jsonMessage = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    user = (User)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonMessage, typeof(User));
                    return user;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                string error = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I don't know how to make refresh token, and cant find good tutorial for that. How to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. If someone need this is my code:

Added SimpleRefreshTokenProvider:

```
    public class SimpleRefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> _refreshTokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>();

        public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            // maybe only create a handle the first time, then re-use for same client
            // copy properties and set the desired lifetime of refresh token
            var refreshTokenProperties = new AuthenticationProperties(context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                IssuedUtc = context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1)
            };
            var refreshTokenTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(context.Ticket.Identity, refreshTokenProperties);

            //_refreshTokens.TryAdd(guid, context.Ticket);
            _refreshTokens.TryAdd(guid, refreshTokenTicket);

            // consider storing only the hash of the handle
            context.SetToken(guid);
        }

        public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {
            AuthenticationTicket ticket;
            if (_refreshTokens.TryRemove(context.Token, out ticket))
            {
                context.SetTicket(ticket);
            }
        }

        public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and in Startup.Authc.cs

```
  OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new FirebirdAuthorizationServerProvider(PublicClientId),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),


            };
```